# Enterprise Architect and Subversion - The ability to import is currently locked

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

After a crash we are trying to get EA and subversion to play nicely with each other.

When I try to check out a package from EA, I get the following Message:

```
The ability to import is currently locked by user: WSxxxx
```

Where WSxxxx is the name of my work station

I tried:

```
svn cleanup : Returns no information
svn status  : Returns no information
From EA Resync Statuses With all all packages
From EA Get Latest : Reports locked then hangs
```

Any idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since svn status doesn't return information, you don't have any edited files in your working copy.

Steal the lock on the file that contains the package (if you're not sure about the file name and location, you can look it up here: right-click on the package in EA, Package Control, Configure...):

- if you're using TortoiseSVN: Get Lock..., and mark checkbox Steal the locks (http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html)
- if you're using svn: svn lock --force  (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.lock.html)

Then unlock the file again, and check out the package in Enterprise Architect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this (if you have e edited files):

1. Copy edited items to another location.
2. Delete the folder containing the problem path.
3. Update the containing folder through Subversion.
4. Copy your files back.

Or:

delete the top level folder and check out again. Hopefully it doesn't come to that though.

Can you look in your .svn folder? There will be a file in it called lock.

```
find . -name 'lock' -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Cheers