# Why does `svn update` unlock files and what is status B

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect, svn-update, svn-lock

I use the Enterprise Architect which used `svn lock` to lock model files inside the the subversion repository. For example:

```
>svn status
     K  Documents\UML\eaB\B2ACB6CFF398.xml
     K  Documents\UML\eaB\BE1936A1AE75.xml
     K  Documents\UML\eaC\C3B74A5737E1.xml
```

I have learned that on `svn commit` you loose the locks unless you use the `--keep-locks` option. Ever since Subversion 1.8 I noticed that `svn update`now **also** unlockes:

```
>svn update
Aktualisiere ».«:
 UB  Documents\UML\eaB\BE1936A1AE75.xml
 UB  Documents\UML\eaB\B2ACB6CFF398.xml
 UB  Documents\UML\eaC\C3B74A5737E1.xml
Hole externen Verweis nach »Homeserver\Library\src\test\resources\config-current«:
Externer Verweis aktualisiert zu Revision 22020.

Revision 22020.

>svn status
```

Note that that there is nothing after `svn status`. The lock are gone! But `svn update` has no `--keep-locks` and no **status B**:

```
>svn help update
update (up): Aktualisiert die Arbeitskopie mit Änderungen aus dem Projektarchiv.
Aufruf: update [PFAD...]

…

    A  Added    - Hinzugefügt
    D  Deleted  - Gelöscht
    U  Updated  - Aktualisiert
    C  Conflict - Konflikt
    G  Merged   - Zusammengeführt
    E  Existed  - Existierend
    R  Replaced  - Ersetzt
```

Ok, it's German. But you don't need to speak German to see there is no **B** in that list.

If I now try to relock the I am told the files are already locked:

```
>svn lock  Documents\UML\eaB\BE1936A1AE75.xml Documents\UML\eaB\B2ACB6CFF398.xml Documents\UML\eaC\C3B74A5737E1.xml
svn: Warnung: W160035: Path '/AndroidApp/trunk/Documents/UML/eaB/BE1936A1AE75.xml' is already locked by user 'martin.krischik' in filesystem '/srv/svn/…/db'
svn: Warnung: W160035: Path '/AndroidApp/trunk/Documents/UML/eaC/C3B74A5737E1.xml' is already locked by user 'martin.krischik' in filesystem '/srv/svn/…/db'
svn: Warnung: W160035: Path '/AndroidApp/trunk/Documents/UML/eaB/B2ACB6CFF398.xml' is already locked by user 'martin.krischik' in filesystem '/srv/svn/…/db'
```

Is this a bug or is there a reason for this weird behaviour.

### Update:

Thanks to @user655063 I now know that **B** stands for *broken lock*. That's leads to the follow on questions: “Why are the locks **always** broken'.

Not just when locked by Enterprise Architect. If I re-lock the files on the command line the locks will be considered broken and un-locked next `svn update` as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html (svn 1.8) and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html (svn 1.7), B means "broken lock".

Is it maybe possible that the locks you had on the files were problematic already before you ran "svn update" (a problem that occurs once in a while when using Enterprise Architect with svn)? See also [Enterprise Architect and Subversion - The ability to import is currently locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783249/enterprise-architect-and-subversion-the-ability-to-import-is-currently-locked/21879182)

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what 'B' stand for. But one questions answered another arises: Why are the lock broken?